# How to fix ‘Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bleu (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for bleu’ error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bleu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bleu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this error happened during installation of some package. The problem occurred because `pip` cannot find a package named `bleu`.So, for quick troubleshooting, you can upgrade

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and retry your installation process.

Comment: what are you trying to install? Please post the `requirement.txt` file or your installation package option.

Comment: i am trying to apply the code of (show attend and tell) https://github.com/yunjey/show-attend-and-tell ... but when i am trying to apply (train.py) i received this message(ImportError: No module named 'bleu'), then i tried to pip bleu but i received this message( Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bleu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bleu)

Comment: this is my requirement.txt :numpy
matplotlib
scipy
scikit-image
hickle
Pillow

Comment: project is supposed to be in python 2. you must use python2 environment to run and install the above project.

Comment: I tried to use python 2 but with python 2 I couldn’t install TensorFlow(  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow)